# Make user friendly url for php blog website

Tags: php, .htaccess, blogs

Current Url = xyz.com/abc/blog-detail.php?id=1

Wanted Url = xyz.com/abc/blog-detail/1

I tried this code in .htaceess already

```
RewriteRule ^blog-detail/([0-9]+) blog-detail.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: This is missing an actual problem description. My guess would be that you have the usual problem caused by `MultiViews`, which happens when the fake URL and physically existing file name overlap like this, so try and disable that.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue using following code in my *.htaccess* file:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best and most flexible way is to implement a router system you may have a look at https://github.com/skipperbent/simple-php-router